# AngularJS: get filtered ng-repeat result count to update my pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, mean-stack, meanjs

**My code explained:**

Below is a simple table with an `ng-repeat` that loops through `ctrl.persons`, and stores the results in the variable `ctrl.results`. There is a filter included that allows a user to search the results using a text input, and `sliceResults` is a custom filter for my [Angular-UI pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) (it determines the offset and limit of results to display based on the current page of the pagination).

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in ctrl.results = (ctrl.persons | filter:searchKeywords) | sliceResults: ctrl.paginationOffset : ctrl.paginationLimit">
        <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Results : {{ ctrl.results.length }}
```

**Situation:**

At the end of the code, `ctrl.results.length` returns the amount of results real-time, and changes accordingly when a user fills out the text input to search through the results.

However, when the amount of results change, my pagination does not change accordingly and therefore shows an incorrect amount of pages (e.g. it can still show 3 pages while there is only 1 page). The amount of pages is based on a variable in my controller (`this.paginationTotalItems`).

**Question:**

How do I update the variable `this.paginationTotalItems` in my controller as soon as the amount of results (`ctrl.results.length`) change in my view? (Or, what alternative way is there to update my pagination?)

**What I tried:**

I am far from being an AngularJS expert, so don't laugh at me! I tried to put a function in `ng-change` with the result count, which failed because apparently it requires `ng-model` and I don't see that working with `ng-repeat`.

I also tried to use `$watch` on the `ctrl.results` variable, but that results in a massive console error because it aborts after x iterations. Also, I'd rather not use `$watch` because I read it only works with `$scope`, which I'd rather not use (I use the "controller as" syntax).

Thanks in advance, I'll accept the answer that helps me solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `$watch` with a controllerAs syntax in the controller. I know you said it's not your priority, but I think it might be your best solution. It will look something like this:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function () {
    var ctrl = this;
    ...
    $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
      return this.results.length;
    }), function (newVal) {
        ctrl.paginationTotalItems = //whatever logic you have
    });
    ....
});
```

**Edit**: Ok so I've just thought of another way that you don't have to use `$scope`. It includes a function on your controller, and calling it using `ng-init` which will update your variable (`ng-init` will fire everytime the iterated list changes):

So after much simplification, your controller will look like this:

```
function MyCtrl() {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.paginationTest = 1;
    ctrl.persons = [1,2,3,4,5];

    ctrl.calcPagination = function () {
        ctrl.paginationTest = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
}
```

And the HTML will be:

```
<table>
          <input ng-model="searchKeywords"/>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in ctrl.results = (ctrl.persons | filter:searchKeywords)" ng-init="ctrl.calcPagination()">

            <td>{{ result }}</td>
            <td>{{ctrl.paginationTest}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/HB7LU/12886/), take a look at the 2nd column, and see that it changes after every change in the input element. In your case you'll just recalculate `ctrl.paginationTotalItems`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, your `$watch` seems to work just fine! I must have messed mine up somehow. But, is there also a way to achieve this without `$watch`? I don't have `$scope` included in my controller (I could add it, but I rather wouldn't).

Comment: @Nic Actually, there might be.. just thought of another way that might suit you. Let me update the answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is answered, but I want to share my experience.

I was having some issues with the use of `ng-init` proposed by @Omri Aharon because it was not calling function each time I changed the value in the text input, I solved it just removing `ng-init` from `<tr>` and adding `ng-change="ctrl.calcPagination()"` to the input.

The HTML code is like:

```
<tbody>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter..." ng-model="ctrl.filterName" ng-change="ctrl.calcPagination()">
  </div>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list | filter: ctrl.filterName | orderBy: ctrl.sortType:ctrl.sortReverse | clientPaginator:ctrl.currentPage:ctrl.itemsPerPage">
    <td>{{item.property}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the function in the controller:

```
ctrl.calcPagination = function(){
    ctrl.resultCount =  $filter('filter')(ctrl.list, ctrl.filterName).length;
}
```

Thanks @Omri Aharon for this simple solution!